# Running multiple graphs in different device modes in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am operating on multiple graphs simultanously.
I would for example, like one graph to use CPU and the other to use the GPU.
How can I achieve this ?

**Current approach and its problems**

When I use a `tf.Session()` with a `tf.ConfigProto` as follows, it does not work and still uses a GPU.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(
            device_count = {'GPU': 0}
        )
```

I have to use the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to disable the use of a GPU. I later on use `os.unsetenv()` to remove this variable after my work.

These solutions are not useful to me because for one graph I want GPUs to be used and for the other I don't want the GPUs to be used. Setting `os.environ()` will affect both the graphs.

How can I achieve my purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

The config created by tf.ConfigProto() can set the visible devices for the sessions. For exmaple:

```
config_cpu = tf.ConfigProto()
config_cpu.gpu_options.visible_device_list=''
sess_cpu = tf.Session(config=config_cpu)

config_gpu = tf.ConfigProto()
config_gpu.gpu_options.visible_device_list='0'
sess_gpu = tf.Session(config=config_gpu)
```

Then the graph in the session, sess_cpu, should run on CPU only and the graph in the session, sess_gpu, should run on GPU 0 only. To prevent tensorflow occupying the whole GPU memory, you can set `config_gpu.gpu_options.allow_growth=True`. Similar configurations can be adopted for your customized needs. You can take a look at the [tf.ConfigProto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto) if you want to use other configurations.

Comment: Can we show me more details about your codes? These configurations are from the tensorflow's protobuf source codes. It works for my cases at least.